# Is HMAC-SHA-1 secure?

Tags: hmac, sha-1

Although SHA-1 theoretically has collisions, HMAC-SHA-1 which is based on SHA-1 is still widely used (in TLS for example) and is considered to be secure. How is that possible?

Comment: http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/hmac-new.html $\;$

Comment: The gist is that the HMAC construction has properties which allow its security definition to be met even if the hash used internally is not a cryptographic hash. It need only meet a weaker definition, which is why HMAC-MD5 is also still considered secure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As shown in [the paper](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/hmac-new.html) Ricky Demer linked in the comments, HMAC can be secure even when the underlying hash function is not collision resistant. Only PRF-ness of the hash function is required, and SHA-1 is not known to lack it. Or a couple of other conditions can suffice even if it isn't a PRF.

Intuitively, it makes sense that HMAC is secure as a MAC even with SHA-1, because a MAC does not allow a collision search. The only way to find the key would be to compromise the *preimage resistance* of SHA-1. HMAC in turn prevents length extension attacks and the like that would allow a forgery without knowing the key.

As an aside, even [HMAC-MD5 hasn't been broken](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9336/13625). However, for the same reason as there – attacks only get better – [I would recommend](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/27530/13625) not choosing SHA-1 as the HMAC hash for new applications if you can just as easily use SHA-2.

Comment: You should update your answer. An attack on HMAC-MD5 has been [found](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/25566/706).

Comment: @mikeazo AFAICT that doesn't seem to qualify as an attack after all?