# Is PBKDF2/RFC 2898 broken because SHA1 is broken?

Tags: sha-1, pbkdf-2, password-hashing

I was attempting to re-implement the [ASP.NET Identity password hash algorithm](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Crypto.cs) in PHP. It uses [RFC 2898](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx), which uses HMAC SHA1. [SHA1 has been broken by google](https://www.theverge.com/2017/2/23/14712118/google-sha1-collision-broken-web-encryption-shattered). Does this mean that RFC 2898 in general and the current ASP.NET Identity password hash format in particular are broken?

Comment: You will probably ease answering if you change RFC 2898 to PBKDF2 which is far more common name.

Comment: HMAC-SHA1 is still safe and this use-case doesn't even suffer from collision attacks anyways.

Comment: @axapaxa edited the title thanks. It was a surprise early this morning.

Comment: Still worth making clear that PBKDF2 is a general construction; even if a SHA-1 vulnerability did have an effect on PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1, it wouldn't mean anything for PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA3 or any other flavor.

Comment: Dupe https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26510/why-is-hmac-sha1-still-considered-secure and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18575/is-hmac-sha-1-secure and nearly https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9336/is-hmac-md5-considered-secure-for-authenticating-encrypted-data

Comment: @hobbs SHA-3 should be using KMAC, not HMAC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That particular usage of SHA-1 uses HMAC, and then iterates that as part of PBKDF2 (which is actually defined for any PRF, not just HMAC-SHA1).

As of this date (2017-05-18) HMAC-SHA1 is unbroken in terms of collisions and other attacks, so PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1 is still considered safe. The HMAC construction, along with the many iterations in PBKDF2, protects against the Google collision attack on SHA1.

However, new applications should move to *at least* SHA2-256 or SHA3-256 as a hashing primitive and not implement *anything* using SHA1 at all unless strictly necessary for compatibility with other systems.

In your case, you need compatibility with older systems, so go ahead, but build in code and make a transition plan to use newer hash function in the near future. Adding simple version field alongside the password hash will suffice in most cases.

Comment: In PBKDF2 using HMAC with SHA-1 as PRF, the PBKDF2 password is the HMAC key (exclusively), and as part fo the specification of HMAC, when that password/key is larger than an SHA-1 message block (64 bytes), it is hashed using SHA-1 before use in HMAC. It follows that colliding SHA-1 messages as obtained by Google's attacks are also equivalent passwords for PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-1. This is an odd fact, but I still agree with the answer, since the PBKDF2 password is supposed to be secret. [reposted with yet another tweak after the 5mn deadline]

Comment: @fgrieu: In any case, the same quirk of HMAC also means that, for any hash *H* and any string *s* longer than the block size of *H*, *s* and *H(s)* are equivalent HMAC-*H* keys, and therefore equivalent passwords for PBKDF2-HMAC-*H*. So you don't actually need the SHA1 collision to construct equivalent passwords.