# finding second pseudo preimage faster than brute force

Tags: hash, preimage-resistance, 2nd-preimage-resistance

As far as I know finding second preimage of a hash function is almost as hard as finding preimage. But I want to know that is there any way to finding second pseudo preimage faster than brute force? I mean ,for example, in MD5 for a given $h$ (hash) we have  $MD5(IV_1 , P_1) = h $.is there any way to find $(IV_2 , P_2)$ such that $$  MD5(IV_2 , P_2) = MD5(IV_1 , P_1) = h$$ in time complexity less than $2^{128}$?

Also if the answer of question is YES please tell me that if I change the $IV$ , is it possible to modify $P$ to get same hash  in time complexity less than $2^{128}$?

Comment: [Strongly related prior question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3441/23623) though that one didn't consider freestart attacks.

Comment: Is "IV" in this question a regular part of the message or the (usually fixed) IV used internally by MD5?

Comment: IV is initial value which is used in MD5

Comment: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-58108-1_19

Comment: kelalaka  this paper is about double block of data. I try to find my answer in one block of data

Comment: @SEJPM it is also called pseudo-preimage ≡ free-start target attack.

Comment: Looked for the references in the Handbook of Applied Cryptography...

Comment: the answer of my question can not be found in Handbook of Applied Cryptography.

Comment: I've only provided a starting point, not the answer.

Comment: thank kelalaka . the answer can also be found by the New Second-Preimage Attacks on Hash Functions

Answer (score 1):

For MD5, it is only known for the first (pseudo) preimage it is given by Yu Sasaki and Kazumaro Aoki in 2009

- [Finding Preimages in Full MD5 Faster than Exhaustive Search](https://iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2009/54790136/54790136.pdf)

> In this paper, we present the first cryptographic preimage attack on the full MD5 hash function. This attack, **with a complexity of $2^{116.9}$, generates a pseudo-preimage of MD5** and, with a complexity of $2^{123.4}$, generates a preimage of MD5.

In the pre-image attack, given a hash function $H$ and a hash value $h$, we try to find $x$ such that $h = H(x)$, In the second preimage attack we are given $H,x,h$ with $h = H(x)$ and we need to find another $x'$ such that $h = H(x')$.

If we can execute a pre-image attack, then we may carry it into a secondary pre-image attack. First, execute a pre-image attack, if we find $y \neq x$ than we are done. If not, continue the search. If brute-forcing, just continue, if a special attack, change the parameters and/or continue to find another.

A similar idea can work for the pseudo secondary preimage attack, too. I've not seen an example on MD5. Usually, the first pseudo preimage attack is extended to secondary pre-image attack. Like done on Gost hash function

[A (Second) Preimage Attack on the GOST Hash Function](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-71039-4_14)

**Note:** *pseudo-preimage* is also called *free-start target attack*.