# Can I clone MD5 hash to a different file?

Tags: md5

one.ttf (**3f67f2feb32a72cf4b90c767eb43aa52**)

two.ttf (**8880bae64dc9e6ba22446f789d09d3d7**)

I want to set one.ttf md5 hash to two.ttf
It is possible?

Like this

one.ttf (**3f67f2feb32a72cf4b90c767eb43aa52**)

two.ttf (**3f67f2feb32a72cf4b90c767eb43aa52**)

Comment: The hash is a direct, deterministic function of the file contents. Changing the hash implies changing the content. Using this the simplest solution is to overwrite two with one. I presume that's not what you want?

Comment: @SEJPM I want to change the font style on my phone.
The system only allowed a TTF font file with a specific MD5 hash.
So, I want to inject that MD5 hash into another font file.

Comment: This is asked [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3441/555), and the answer is no if we ignore hacks of the phone code, which are off-[topic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and the remote possibility that one.ttf was crafted to allow that.